# How do I write a query using except to compare the data in two tables having the same columns

Tags: sql, subquery

How do I write a query using except to compare the data in two tables having the same columns confiscated (huge data can't compare manually) and should give results as matched or not?

I tried the below query and strucked to proceed further to show data matched or not. Please help me with this.

```
(select CATEGORY_ID,PERIOD_CODE,RETAIL_ID,Transhipment_Ind,(EQ_VOLUME),(CONSUMER_UNITS)
from  vwAGG_CAT_STORE)
except
SELECT PERIOD_CODE,RETAIL_ID,TRANSSHIPMENT_IND,P.CATEGORY_ID,SUM(EQ_VOLUME) AS "EQVOLUME",SUM(CONSUMER_UNITS) AS "CONSUMER_UNITS"
FROM vwFCT_DISTSTORE F
INNER JOIN vwDIM_PROD P ON (P.PRODUCT_ID=F.PRODUCT_ID) 
GROUP BY PERIOD_CODE,RETAIL_ID,TRANSSHIPMENT_IND,P.CATEGORY_ID
```

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN perhaps.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain on simpler tables:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.*
FROM TABLE1
FULL JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.C = TABLE2.C
WHERE TABLE1.C IS NULL OR TABLE2.C IS NULL
```

This way, all the TABLE1 entities that don't have pairs in TABLE2 will be listed and vice-versa.